# SAS data merge for existence

Tags: sas

I am new to sas, i have two datasets as following,

```
data datasetA;
    input a $1;
    datalines;
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
;
run;

data datasetB;
    input a $1;
    datalines;
1
3
5
7
;
run;
```

If a appears B, then my desired output should be

```
1 Y
2 N
3 Y
4 N
5 Y
6 N
7 Y
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achived by in at least two ways:

- `merge` via the `data step` or
- `left join` with the `proc sql`.

This pdf compares [pros and cons of merge versus sql in sas](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2008/178-2008.pdf).

Since rbet showed you how to do this with the merge step, I'll show you how to do it with the `proc sql`.

```
proc sql;
  create table work.result as
    select t1.a, case when t2.a is not missing then 'Y' else 'N' end as exists
    from work.datasetA t1
     left join work.datasetB t2 on t1.a = t2.a order by t1.a;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
data _a;
format a 3.;
do i = 1 to 7;
a = i;
output;
end;
drop i;

data _b;
format b 3.;
do i = 1 to 7 by 2;
b = i;
output;
end;
drop i;
run;

data _c;
merge _a(in=_a) _b(in=_b rename=(b=a));
format St $2.;
if _a and _b then St = 'Y';
else St = 'N';
by a;
run;
```

I would suggest you to google `SAS merge` or `SAS proc sql join` for introduction to basic concepts.