# Left join of tables with specific instructions

Tags: sas, left-join

Would you kindly be able to assist me with writing SAS script for a specific type of left join as described below?

I’m looking to do a left join of Table – A to Table B [given below], where full matching of all identifying fields or partial matching [at least 1 field] with the remaining fields in Table – B being missing/ null is also treated a missing; however, any partial/ full matching with at least one field populated in Table – B whilst being null/ missing in Table – A will be treated as non-match.

Here’s an example of input tables [A and B] and output matching analysis/ results below:

TABLE - A

```
S/N   COL_1   COL_2   COL_3   COL_4
-----------------------------------
1     A       p               ii
2     A
3     B       r
```

TABLE - B

```
S/N   COL_1   COL_2   COL_3   COL_4
-----------------------------------
1     A       p               ii
2     A       q
3     A
4     A       p       7       ii
5     B
6     B       r               n
```

OUTPUT/ MATCHING ANALYSIS

```
TABLE - A   TABLE - B   MATCH   NO MATCH
----------------------------------------
1           1           Y
1           2                   N
1           3           Y
1           4                   N
2           1                   N
2           2                   N
2           3           Y
2           4                   N
3           5           Y
3           6                   N
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Please post what you've tried so far.

Comment: [A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29273568/sas-data-merge-for-existence) was asked earlier, you should be able to use either of the two answers as a starting point. Some additional conditional logic will be required.

Comment: Were also not trying to drive users away...a simple "Please post what you've tried so far" would have been enough.

Comment: @CarolinaJay65 I'm perfectly happy to drive users away who are asking for others to write code for them, rather than use this site how it should be (asking about concepts, and asking for help with what they've done).  It's not just that they need to write what they've tried; there are cases where it's fine to not do so.  But posting requirements is something I'm very tired of seeing without the $100 an hour I would expect to complete them.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided not to use join as there could be more than 4 columns to join...

First,
let's find the equals:

```
    proc sql;
      create table Equals as 
      select a.*,'Y' as Match, '' as No_Match from table_a as a
      intersect 
      select b.*,'Y' as Match, '' as No_Match from table_b as b ;
    quit;
```

Now, let's fine not equals:

```
   proc sql;
     create table Not_Equals as 
     select a.*,'' as Match, 'N' as No_Match from table_a as a
     except
     select b.*,'' as Match, 'N' as No_Match from table_b as b
     union 
     select b.*,'' as Match, 'N' as No_Match from table_b as b
     except
     select a.*,'' as Match, 'N' as No_Match from table_a as a  ;
   quit;
```

and finally - let's merge the 2 data sets:

```
    data All;
      set Equals Not_Equals;
    run;
```