# Compare a variable in two different data-sets in SAS

Tags: sas

I need to compare two variables in two different data-sets which has different names for the variables, then i need to write the observations in SASYES if the records match else write it to SASNO.

I am retrieving the records from DB2 and renaming the variables.

**my sas code**

```
DATA _NULL_;
   SET WORKLIST;
   SET UNITFUNC;
   IF PRIMNUM=CORRPMNM AND MODELCD=MCMODEL THEN DO; 
      FILE SASYES; 
      PUT @01  ANSFACT1 $CHAR7. 
          @09  CORRPMNM $CHAR12.
          @21  MCMODEL  $CHAR8. 
      OUTPUT SASYES; 
   END; 
   ELSE DO; 
      FILE SASNO; 
      PUT  @01  ANSFACT1 $CHAR7. 
           @09  CORRPMNM $CHAR12. 
           @21  MCMODEL  $CHAR8. 
      OUTPUT SASNO;
   END;
RUN;
```

When i submit the code, all the observations are written to `SASNO` even when they are few matching observations in both the data-sets. Please help me.

Note: I have had used `MERGE` also to read the data from two tables, the result is same.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: It would help if you could create small datasets from `WORKLIST` and `UNITFUNC`, that includes at least one example of when it works as you expect and at leas one example of where it does not.

Comment: This question covers the same issue, but with some alterations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29273568/sas-data-merge-for-existence/29274177#29274177 Take a look if this is suitable for you as well.

Comment: Yes. But i have to check condition for three variables. If all the three variables match only then it has to write to the file; you see this is where it gets complicated.

Comment: You are only comparing two variables in the code. But nonetheless, by extending the join in the answer that I pointed you to, you should be able to get the desired result.

And if you add some example datasets on what you have and what you want, it will probably be quite easy to show the actual code as well.

Comment: Thank You. It is working now. But i will get only true data. How would i get the records which do not have matching records. Should i try same query but instead of 'equals', could i use 'notequals'?

Comment: It would be great if you could add your current code to the question now. It is probably easier to lead you right then.

Comment: `PROC SQL;                                        
   CREATE TABLE NEWSASTY AS                      
   SELECT T1.A, T1.C, T2.P,                      
          T1.M, T2.W                             
     FROM UNITFUNC T1                            
     JOIN WORKLIST T2 ON T1.C = T2.P             
      AND T1.M = T2.W;                           
QUIT; `

Answer (score 0):

SET takes one row at a time, never comparing across datasets.  Like taking one stack of cards and setting it on top of another, then taking one card at a time.

MERGE combines two datasets, so you take two stacks of cards and place them side by side and look at the top from each pile at one time.  So that's what you want to do here: merge them.

```
data compare;
  merge ds1 ds2;
  by commonID;
run;
```

You might want to merge `by` an ID variable, or you might want to merge without a `by` statement to just compare the first record from each dataset, the second from each dataset, etc.

```
data compare;
  merge ds1 ds2;
run;
```

You can add code in that data step to further limit what is output, or you can just merge into one dataset then look at it visually and create additional code afterwards.

Comment: I cannot use merge because the records may or may not be in the same order. They are scattered all over the data set. How do i compare these scattered records is my question,they are not in order.

Comment: Then you haven't described your question sufficiently in the question.  You must use merge, or sql join, or something similar: but you must be able to state the conditions under which you have a valid combination.  Are you trying to merge them on `PRIMNUM=CORRPMNM AND MODELCD=MCMODEL `?

Comment: Sorry about that. Nope. If i use merge, i am using this FACTRY_CD which is common to both data-sets.

Comment: Then I don't see how a merge isn't what you're looking for.  You may want to supply data (before and after) to get at what you want.