# Using variables from different datasets in one data step

Tags: sas

I have two datasets, one with Student ID code and the other with the students' camp profile number. In my other dataset, I have the students' personal information and their student ID code. Some students already have a camp profile number but the majority don't. I need to compare the student ID numbers and create a dataset with their camp profile number for those that are in the camp profile system. With that information, I can then create camp profile numbers for the students without one.

```
data work.campID;
      set o.campStudents e.studentInfo;
      if (o.campStudents).studentID = (e.studentInfo).studentID then 
           newVar=(o.campStudents).campID;
run;
```

My question is how do I compare the student ID number from the one dataset with the other? I know that the way above is not possible, but it's essentially what would be done with SQL. I need a way to reference that variable from the 1st dataset with the same variable in the 2nd using SAS.

Here's a similar question [Compare a variable in two different data-sets in SAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29747187/compare-a-variable-in-two-different-data-sets-in-sas) except I'm not looking to merge.

Comment: How is your question actually different from the linked question?  You *do* want to merge - or at least, you have to merge in some fashion (join, format, etc.)

Comment: Is there no way to call on the dataset variables like I am asking? Is the only way to do this to merge?

Comment: What you're describing _is_ a merge.  You want to take one dataset, and find the corresponding row in the other dataset, and place some variable(s) from the other dataset alongside the row in the first dataset, right?  That is exactly what merge does.

Comment: Not to say there aren't a dozen ways to do this - but they all require something not dissimilar to merge.  If you can explain why you don't like using merge, perhaps a better alternative amongst the various options can be presented.  Do you have multi-GB datasets you want to avoid sorting, for example?  What's your concern with merge?

Comment: This is a look up and in SAS the ways to do a look up are: `MERGE` (DATA STEP), `JOIN` (SQL) and `FORMAT`.

Comment: And hash and keyed set and... ; the point is there are many ways, but picking one specific choice requires more information.

Comment: Thank you for explaining more about a merge. It is what I needed and I ended up using a match merge specifically. The solution provided in the other question did not work at first, but I realized I had to use a proc sort on the two datasets before I merged them with a by.